# Eclipse can't find javax.persistence.Entity even though jar is present

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, spring-boot

I need to use the `@Entity` annotation but I can't import it from `javax.persistence.Entity` even though I have the jar:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clearly not in the classpath.  Or you need a better IDE - IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`  ( path will be something like `C:\Users\home\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence`  , guessed from your screenshot )
2. update your maven project :

   > Right click on your project -> Maven -> Update Project